# Installing django with python 2.5 and not with the default version of python

Tags: python, django

I have to install Django on my linux server where python 2.4 is available as the default installation. I have installed python 2.5 as a separate version. Now I have to install Django which I have to use with python 2.5. Is there any specific requirement, so that it is installed with the python 2.5 and not with the default 2.4 version available on the server ?

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

after downloading the django source, instead of doing

```
python setup.py install
```

do

```
/path/to/python2.5 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

Django is 100% compatible with Python 2.4. However if you really want to use 2.5 you would probably be best off using a virtualenv and installing Django and your project inside that.

Don't forget if you do try and install 2.5, you will also need to recompile mod_wsgi to use it, as the system packaged version will only use 2.4.