# installed new version of python, but django still uses system default

Tags: python, django, dreamhost

On Dreamhost, I did the following

- installed Python 2.7.1 in my ~/opt directory,
- added `export PATH=$HOME/opt/bin/:$PATH` in my .bash_profile
- verified with `python --version` that 2.7.1 was default
- installed setuptools 0.6c11-py2.7
- installed Django 1.2.4 with `/path/to/python2.7 setup.py install`
- verified version 1.2.4 with `import django` and `django.VERSION` in python shell
- `wget http://wiki.dreamhost.com/django-setup.py`
- `python2.7 django-setup.py` in my site directory ("site.com")
- intentionally put a syntax error in ~/site.com/project/urls.py
- visited the site in web browser and the error page **still** says I'm using Python 2.5.2

Why does my Django refuse to use my new version of Python?

According to this, [installing-django-with-python-2-5-and-not-with-the-default-version-of-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139372/installing-django-with-python-2-5-and-not-with-the-default-version-of-python), the problem might be with mod_wsgi (or I think passenger in my case (but I don't actually know if they do the same thing)).

Should I try to compile mod_wsgi, compile passenger_wsgi, install virtualenv, all of the above, none of the above, A and C, B D and E, or something else altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can [change the WSGIPythonExecutable directive](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonExecutable) in your mod_wsgi configuration?

To configure Passenger's Python interpretter, you can [follow these steps](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Passenger_WSGI#Passenger_WSGI_and_virtualenv).

Comment: Thank you, Evan!

your second suggestion worked.  :-)
http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Passenger_WSGI#Passenger_WSGI_and_virtualenv

Comment: WSGIPythonExecutable was removed in mod_wsgi 3.0 and so not in current versions of mod_wsgi. It also would not have helped for mod_wsgi anyway. The only way you can have mod_wsgi use a different major/minor version of Python is to rebuild it from source code as it compiles against the specific version and cannot be used against different major/minor version of Python.